# How to iterate upwards and downwards to infinity with one variable

Tags: loops, recursion

I am just getting started with Prolog, and I am really stuck, I have been trying for days to get this to work for ages so really hope someone can help. I am being asked to make it so that if someone enters

```
userInput(X).
```

What will come out is

```
X=0; X=1; X=-1; X=2; X=-2;
```

and so on for infinity.

I am aware of how to do this infinitely upwards, using:

```
between(0, inf, X).
```

I am also aware of how to do this infinitely downwards, using:

```
example(X):- var(X), X=0.
example(X):- var(X), example(Y), X is Y-1.
```

I understand that this could also be done positively iterating upwards using `+` instead.

But to have `X` switch from positive to negative counting is not working at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you pass a second argument that controls the `+` and the `-` and you could call it `sign`?

Comment: *But to have `X` switch from positive to negative counting is not working at all.* Do you mean you have some code you tried and it's not working? Do you have a question about your code? Perhaps you could show what you've tried.

Comment: Did you correctly post the example: Is `X=-1; X=-2` correct or is it suppose to be `X=-1; X=2; X=-2;` ? Both can be done, but just checking as it is easy to make a typo.

Comment: Sorry guy coder you are right, it should go X=-1, then X=2, then X=-2 and so on. Guy Coder with the second argument, this is what I want to achieve but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an *accumulator* that starts with `0`, is updated throught the sequence and each time "emits" its result, so:

```
userInput(X) :-
    userInput(0,X).
```

Now each time you unify `X` with the accumulator:

```
userInput(X,X).
```

the recursive case(s) of course has to determine the next item, and you can use the following guide:

- if the number `X` is less than or equal to zero, the new `X2` is `X2 is -X+1`; and
- if the number `X` is greater than zero, the new `X2` is `X2 is -X`.

You can write these as:

```
userInput(X,R) :-
    X =< 0,
    !,
    X2 is -X+1,
    userInput(X2,R).
userInput(X,R) :-
    X2 is -X,
    userInput(X2,R).
```

Or putting it all together:

```
userInput(X) :-
    userInput(0,X).

userInput(X,X).
userInput(X,R) :-
    X =< 0,
    !,
    X2 is -X+1,
    userInput(X2,R).
userInput(X,R) :-
    X2 is -X,
    userInput(X2,R).
```

This generates:

```
?- userInput(X).
X = 0 ;
X = 1 ;
X = -1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = -2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = -3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = -4 ;
X = 5 ;
X = -5 ;
X = 6 ;
X = -6 ;
X = 7 ;
X = -7
```

**Alternative**:

an alternative that is even easier is simply first stating that `0` is a `userInput/1`:

```
userInput(0).
```

and then use an accumulator for the other cases that starts with `1`:

```
userInput(X) :-
    userInput(1,X).
```

Now each iteration, you unify `X` as a result, and `-X` as a result, and in the recursive case, you increment `X`. So:

```
userInput(X,X).
userInput(X,NX) :-
    NX is -X.
userInput(X,R) :-
    X1 is X+1,
    userInput(X1,R).
```

Or putting it all together:

```
userInput(0).
userInput(X) :-
    userInput(1,X).

userInput(X,X).
userInput(X,NX) :-
    NX is -X.
userInput(X,R) :-
    X1 is X+1,
    userInput(X1,R).
```